# Adding Tweets of people I follow in Drupal website

Tags: drupal, twitter, drupal-7

So I am developing a website using drupal. And I want to create a view of twitter tweets that a posted by me and by people i follow on twitter. I tried to use [Twitter](https://drupal.org/project/twitter) module. But with this module I can see only my own tweets. If I want to add tweets from other account, I have to manually add the account under twitter settings. I would really appreciate if anyone knows how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this for showing a user's timeline : http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-display-tweets-using-embedded-timelines-drupal-7

Is that what you want? I hope so!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for: [Twitter streaming](https://drupal.org/project/twitterstream)